# equality test between childNodes(0).values and a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I can't to work my code.

I have 3 files:

piante.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FMPXMLRESULT
xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"><ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE><PRODUCT
BUILD="12-06-2016" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 15.0.3"/><DATABASE
DATEFORMAT="D/m/yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="IndexHorti v3.12.fmp12" RECORDS="586"
TIMEFORMAT="k:mm:ss "/>

<METADATA><FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Gen Spe con spazio"
TYPE="TEXT"/><FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Localizzazione esemplare LAST"
TYPE="TEXT"/><FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Link WEB"
TYPE="TEXT"/></METADATA>

<RESULTSET FOUND="2">

<ROW MODID="56" RECORDID="20055">
<COL><DATA>Acanthus  mollisL.</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>01-02-01-23</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>www.corriere.it</DATA></COL></ROW>

<ROW MODID="12" RECORDID="20057">
<COL><DATA>Achillea  millefolium L.</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>01-05-01-16</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>www.repubblica.it</DATA></COL></ROW>
</RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

then a function that parses the XML doc and return the third Child if the second child matches with the string "ulink"

```
function getLink(fname, ulink)

{

try //Internet Explorer
  {
  docname=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

  }
catch(e)
  {
  try //Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, etc.
    {
    docname=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);

    }
  catch(e) {alert(e.message)}
  try 
  {
  docname.async=false;
  docname.load(fname);

  }
catch(e) {alert(e.message)}

  }

var x=docname.getElementsByTagName("ROW");
document.write(x.length);
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){ 

  var y=x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATA");
  document.write(y[0].childNodes(0).nodeValue);
  document.write(y[1].childNodes(0).nodeValue);
  document.write(y[2].childNodes(0).nodeValue);
  if(y[1].childNodes(0).nodeValue == ulink){
      var z= y[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
     document.write(y[2].childNodes(0).nodeValue);
      return z;}
      else{document.write("not equal");}
     }
}
```

and then the file provadef.html to testing

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="byxml.js"> 
</script>
</head>

<body>


<div>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.write(getLink("piante.xml","01-02-01-23"));
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I insert some doument.write instructions to debug, but I can' t understand the error. can u help me please?

Comment: Understand what error? You didn't post an error ?

Comment: Note that `document.write` ***overwrites*** the entire document, including your elements and scripts.

Comment: You're using `document.write` for debugging? Use the console, and spend a little time getting to know the dev tools in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you write `childNodes(0)`, you should be writing `childNodes[0]`.

`childNodes` is an array, and array elements should be accessed using square brackets.

Parentheses are used for grouping expressions and for calling functions (the latter of which is the syntax you used).